# How to get rid of the BootstrapVersion parameter with cdk synth?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

When generating the cloudformation template with aws cdk:

```
cdk synth
```

I always get:

```
  "Parameters": {
    "BootstrapVersion": {
      "Type": "AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>",
      ...
```

Here the code:

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Stack } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as sqs from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sqs';

export class MyStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
    super(scope, id);
    
    const queue = new sqs.Queue(this, 'Example', {
      visibilityTimeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(300)
    });
  }
};

const app = new cdk.App();
new MyStack(app, 'MyStack');
```

Full output (some shortening ...):

```
$ cdk synth 
Resources:
  ExampleA925490C:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      VisibilityTimeout: 300
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Delete
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: MyStack/Example/Resource
  CDKMetadata:
    Type: AWS::CDK::Metadata
    Properties:
      Analytics: v2:deflate64:H4sIAAAAAAAA/zPSM9EzUEwsL9ZNTsnWzclM0qsOLklMztYBCsUXFxbrVQeWppam6jin5YEZtSBWUGpxfmlRMljUOT8vJbMkMz+vVicvPyVVL6tYv8zQTM8YaGpWcWamblFpXklmbqpeEIQGAChZc6twAAAA
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: MyStack/CDKMetadata/Default
    Condition: CDKMetadataAvailable
Conditions:
  CDKMetadataAvailable:
    Fn::Or:
      - Fn::Or:
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - af-south-1
          ...
      - Fn::Or:
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - us-west-1
          ...
Parameters:
  BootstrapVersion:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: /cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version
    Description: Version of the CDK Bootstrap resources in this environment, automatically retrieved from SSM Parameter Store. [cdk:skip]
Rules:
  CheckBootstrapVersion:
    Assertions:
      - Assert:
          Fn::Not:
            - Fn::Contains:
                - - "1"
                  - "2"
                  - "3"
                  - "4"
                  - "5"
                - Ref: BootstrapVersion
        AssertDescription: CDK bootstrap stack version 6 required. Please run 'cdk bootstrap' with a recent version of the CDK CLI.
```

Here the environment:

```
$ cdk doctor
ℹ️ CDK Version: 2.8.0 (build 8a5eb49)
ℹ️ AWS environment variables:
  - AWS_PAGER = 
  - AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE = sbxb.admin
  - AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS = regional
  - AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED = 1
  - AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG = 1
ℹ️ No CDK environment variables
```

How to get rid of that cloudformation parameter?
I just want to use CDK to create a cloudformation template.

Later I want to use that template with the service catalog and don't want the `BootstrapVersion` parameter to be exposed nor do I need it.

Comment: Are you planning to deploy the generated CloudFormation template separately or using the `cdk deploy` command?

Comment: @KaustubhKhavnekar I am planning to deploy it seperately with `aws cloudformation` not with cdk!

Comment: @Paolo this is completely independent of the content of my stack I guess. Here some excerpts:

The app is something like:
```
const app = new cdk.App();
new EMRStack(app, 'EMRStack', {
  env: { account: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT, region: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION },
});
```
The stack is created like:
```
export class EMRStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: EMRStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
   ...
```

Comment: @Paolo I will. But the example you mention does create the unwanted Parameters.

Comment: @Paolo is probably using CDK v1, see my answer

Comment: Thanks @KaustubhKhavnekar your hint worked. It needed some try and errors to find the correct code. I have created an answer containing the code.

Comment: If you are looking to use the template with service catalog.  You can write products directly with code using the `ProductStack`.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-servicecatalog.ProductStack.html

Answer (score 15):

Here the modified code which works:

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { DefaultStackSynthesizer, Stack } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as sqs from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sqs';

export class MyStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const queue = new sqs.Queue(this, 'Example', {
      visibilityTimeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(300)
    });
  }
};

const app = new cdk.App();
new MyStack(app, 'MyStack' , {
  synthesizer: new DefaultStackSynthesizer({
    generateBootstrapVersionRule: false
  })
});
```

As mentioned by the other answer one has to override the DefaultStackSynthesizer with `generateBootstrapVersionRule: false`.

Comment: See, below. BootstraplessSynthesizer works better.

Answer (score 7):

Edit: updated the answer to mention the `generateBootstrapVersionRule` parameter. See @Felix's answer for code.

By default, the following is included in all templates when using `DefaultStackSynthesizer`:

```json
"Parameters": {
    "BootstrapVersion": {
      "Type": "AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>",
      "Default": "/cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version",
      "Description": "Version of the CDK Bootstrap resources in this environment, automatically retrieved from SSM Parameter Store. [cdk:skip]"
    }
  },
  "Rules": {
    "CheckBootstrapVersion": {
      "Assertions": [
        {
          "Assert": {
            "Fn::Not": [
              {
                "Fn::Contains": [
                  [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4",
                    "5"
                  ],
                  {
                    "Ref": "BootstrapVersion"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "AssertDescription": "CDK bootstrap stack version 6 required. Please run 'cdk bootstrap' with a recent version of the CDK CLI."
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

The `BootstrapVersion` parameter and the associated rule are used by CDK to check the version of the [Bootstrap stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/bootstrapping.html) which is deployed in your environment. You can remove it if you are confident that your stack doesn't require bootstrapping or you have the correct `BootstrapVersion`. The parameter isn't used anywhere else in stack.

By default, CDK v2 uses the `DefaultStackSynthesizer` so this parameter will always be included. One way of avoid this is to create a custom object with `generateBootstrapVersionRule` parameter with a value of false (see Felix's answer for code). Alternatively can also specify the `LegacyStackSynthesizer` when instantiating the CDK to avoid creating the parameter, however this makes a few changes in the way your stack is synthesized and how you use the bootstrap stack. A table of differences is given in the v1 documentation link below.

CDK v1 is the opposite and uses the `LegacyStackSynthesizer` by default.

References

- https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/17942#issuecomment-992295898
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/bootstrapping.html#bootstrapping-synthesizers (v2 documentation)
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v1/guide/bootstrapping.html#bootstrapping-synthesizers (v1 documentation)

Comment: That worked. See other answer for the full working code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out we don't need to use `LegacyStackSynthesizer`

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to the great answers above. Another way to skip the bootstrap parameters is to use [BootstraplessSynthesizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.BootstraplessSynthesizer.html). Here is how to integrate it in your code

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Stack } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as sqs from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sqs';

export class MyStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
    super(scope, id);
    
    const queue = new sqs.Queue(this, 'Example', {
      visibilityTimeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(300)
    });
  }
};

const app = new cdk.App();
new MyStack(app, 'MyStack', {
  synthesizer: new cdk.BootstraplessSynthesizer({})
});
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do the same using Python CDK in the below mentioned manner :

```
import aws_cdk as cdk
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
)


class CloudformationStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:

        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, stack_name="cloudformation-stack-management" ,**kwargs)

        ## CDK resources


app = cdk.App()
CloudformationStack(app, "test-stack",
                    synthesizer=cdk.DefaultStackSynthesizer(generate_bootstrap_version_rule=False))

app.synth()
```